# Where is UseDefaultServiceProvider on Net6's WeBapplicationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-5

I have a unit test which uses the following in order to fully validate all dependency injection configuration:

```cs
public class StartupTests
{
    public void ConfigurationIsValid()
    {
        var host = Program.CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>())
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider(
                (_, options) =>
                {
                    options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
                    options.ValidateScopes = true;
                });
                
        var action = () => host.Build();
        
        action.Should().NotThrow();
    }
}
```

This works well when using the .NET 5 `IHostBuilder` from `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()`, but I am trying to find where the `UseDefaultServiceProvider()` method is on the new `WebApplicationBuilder` that was introduced in .NET 6.

Answer (score 7):

This method is an extension on the `WebApplicationBuilder.Host` property in .NET 6.

The updated unit test looks like this:

```cs
public void ConfigurationIsValid()
{
    var builder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>());
    builder.Host.UseDefaultServiceProvider(
        (_, options) =>
        {
            options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
            options.ValidateScopes = true;
        });

    var action = () => builder.Build();

    action.Should().NotThrow();
}
```